# Angular ngOnChanges can not read property first time

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access data from an input to a component, and using ngOnChanges to do so, but throwing error in console like `"can not read property 'name' of undefined"` but data loading  properly.

After debugging, this issue occurs only when page refresh. First time data would be undefined and second time data is loading.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Input() data: any;

 ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if(changes['data']) {
      this.dispEn = this.data.name.en;
      this.dispDe = this.data.name.en;
              }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put a test around data to catch when it does have a value

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
  if(changes['data'] && this.data) {
    this.dispEn = this.data.name.en;
    this.dispDe = this.data.name.en;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

better to use the setter here

```
@Input('data) set dataInfo(dnfo: any){
   // ToDo method implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'change' object if it has the data then check whether the change is the first change:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if((changes['data'] && !changes.data.isFirstChange()){
        this.dispEn = this.data.name.en;
        this.dispDe = this.data.name.en;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnChanges will fire when the inputs are first checked when the component is initialized. You can check whether the change is the first change using [isFirstChange()](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange#isfirstchange)

```js
 ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges) {
    if (!simpleChanges.data.isFirstChange()) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: This can still cause "can not read property 'name' of undefined". Data needs to be checked for a value.